# SQLiteDatabase dbm = this.getWritableDatabase(); recursive

Tags: android, sqlite, getwritabledatabase

Help! I'm transferring geolocation data from android to the database. Gives an error message. Error: (45, 46) error: can not find symbol method getWritableDatabase (). Help!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq9tw.jpg)

```
public class AndroidGPSTrackingActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnShowLocation;

    // GPSTracker class
    GPSTracker gps;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // create class object
                gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);

                // check if GPS enabled
                if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                    SQLiteDatabase dbm = this.getWritableDatabase();
                    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();


                    cv.put("LAT_G",
                            gps.getLatitude());

                    cv.put("LANG",  gps.getLongitude());

                    boolean result = dbm.insert("table name", cv);


                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    // can't get location
                    // GPS or Network is not enabled
                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                } 
     }  }); }  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`getWritableDatabase()` is a method in [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html). `this` in your code refers to the `View.OnClickListener` anon inner class instance that is not a `SQLiteOpenHelper` nor has such method in it.

You'd need to implement your own class extending `SQLiteOpenHelper`, instantiate it, and then call `getWritableDatabase()` on the instance to obtain an `SQLiteDatabase` to work with.

Comment: Could you give an example? I do not quite understand.